# How large should be Data Transfer Objects?

Tags: java, oop, dto

As I understand, Data Transfer Objects are used for different purposes, so let's bound the scope with the view layer in Java (JSF) -based web-applications (i.e. there are usually  some entity-objects mapped on a DB, which can be also used in a Business-Logic layer, and some transfer objects used in a presentation layer).

So, I have some misunderstanding about how should well-designed DTOs look. Should I keep them as small as possible? Or should I try to pass with them as much information as possible and design them in such way that only some (different in different use-cases) part of the DTO fields is initialized at a time?

Should I consider using some OO principles (at least inheritance and composition) when designing DTOs or they should be as simple as only a number of primitive-type fields with their accessors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DTOs, if at all different from the domain objects/entities, should be as big as needed - you should transfer exactly all data that you need.

Comment: so, how do you think, is it a good/bad idea to create big DTOs (I can even call them containers) with lots of properties, a part of which won't be initialized at one time, and another part at another time, and sometimes all of them will be initialized? Or you'd better create several DTOs and use one or another or all together depending on the use-case?

Comment: several depending on the use case if  they would differ greatly. The difference of 1 or 2 fields isn't important.

Answer (score 1):

DTOs in any language should be pretty light weight.  Whether or not to use inheritance is a question only you could answer - it really depends on the business needs.  Otherwise the DTO itself should include the basic get/set properties.

Generally these objects are pretty light weight, however it really depends on the data / properties you need.  If your DTO has 1 property vs 50 properties, if you need 50 so be it.  When it comes time to passing data to functions / methods the DTO saves your life from having to add all those extra parameters.  You're essentially just passing one object.

Answer (score 1):

DTOs should be as lightweight as possible, distinct from the business objects, and limited in scope (for example *package* level objects).

I say they should be separate from the business objects, contrary to Bozho's statement "if at all different from the domain objects", because a DTO will often need setters that users of the business object should not use.

I have, for example, a Person object and a PersonDTO... the DTO needs a setter for the person's name (first, last, etc.) but that is retrieved from an external data source and my application is not allowed to change it, so my business object "Person" shouldn't have a setter.